# ScrollView not scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

i am trying to add images to my relative layout with an for loop but it isn't working.
I tried to remove the for loop and making one image longer and the scroll view seems to work the but when i try to add more than one image to the relative layou it adds it but i cant scroll through them.
Meaning that i can see that there are 5 images but i can only see the top half of it and cant scroll to see the bottom half.

Here is my xml that i use for the activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/MainRelativeLayout"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.tutecentral.tvtimeschedule.app.MainActivity"
            android:background="#87CABE"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the activity that i use to add the images

```
        int amountOfChannels = 9;
        int paddingTopOfImage = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= amountOfChannels; i++) {

            //ImageView Setup
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            //setting image resource
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.channel_1);
            //setting image position

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 400;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 1000;

            imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setY(paddingTopOfImage);

            //adding view to layout
            RelativeLayout mainRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainRelativeLayout);
            mainRelativeLayout.addView(imageView);

            paddingTopOfImage = paddingTopOfImage + 450;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to put ScrollView under LinearLayout, because ScrollView by default is LinearLayout. Try Removing the LinearLayout.